# Long Non English Text Slows UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

been trying to use Long non English text (Persian) get to work in UITableview with a simple UILabel with no extra view and just 2 or 3 constraint , even with fixed height so no extra height calculations with opaque and non transparent backgrounds and clipToBounds set to true .
the Tableview pattern is right cause been using it a while and its working just fine with English texts with more that 1000 chars. 
the text is just plain and not attributed , its been my problem for months and found similar questions without answers since a year ago.

so any idea how to solve this issue ?
any way to call label.text = ... just once in cellforRow ? or doing it async somehow without messing things ?
tried cell caching and got no results
using CoreText or CATextLayer was just so complex for my situation as the cell is complex and I thought this may be causing the problem so I started testing on simple cell with a label and the problem is still there 
I've seen similar cases in apps like instagram or telegram without any problem so there might be a way ?

thanks in advance

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TempTextCell", for: indexPath) as! TempTextCell
     cell.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.contentLabel.text = TestVC.data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TestVC.data.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

lines for label is set to 0 and wordWrap so the height will be dynamic but it will lag even with fixed height anyway

Comment: your question is not clear ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @vivekDas uitableview with cells containing 500 char persian texts without lagging in scroll

Comment: Still not clear ?

Comment: @vivekDas lol probably pass this one maybe , what is un clear ? Have you ever had non english text in your app ? Cause if you had then this was your problem cause the table is as simple as a hello world but lags on non english

Comment: Please post the "hello world" example you have, so that we can explore where the problem is. Persian (and Arabic) are a bit slower to render than English (glyph determination is more complicated and there are a *lot* more ligatures), but this should be solvable (as you note). Getting this down to a simple app that does nothing but display static English vs. Persian text is definitely the first step to solving it.

Comment: @RobNapier let me grab some code and see how simple it is

Comment: (BTW, when you say non-English, I assume you specifically mean Persian and similar alphabets. I wouldn't expect this problem with Cyrillic for example, since it is much closer to Latin in terms of layout.)

Comment: @RobNapier yea i mean persian but i've seen similar problems with hindi or arabic texts so just wanted to not to be specific on a lang

Comment: Thanks. yeah, then that's definitely the kind of problem I was expecting. Hindi has similar glyph challenges as the languages that use Arabic-script. Latin is so easy :D

Comment: @RobNapier :( added some code , its useless cause its simple and its not working

Comment: you can use dispatch async to load text to the UILable, or create one array of UILable with text loaded and just add it to cell while displaying.

Comment: @vivekDas tried both of these  the labels will all be empty forever test them in your way if you got time and let me know if any result